# Unable to include android ndk in cmake visual studio

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

I was trying to make a cross platform imgui project in visual studio 2022, starting with android. In the beginning, I was not able to include some android libraries properly, so after following several tutorials, I ended up with this CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform), include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform)")

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Users/HP/source/repos/CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform)/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/")

find_package(imgui REQUIRED)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeTarget "CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform).cpp" "CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform).h" "imgui_android.cpp" "imgui_impl_android.cpp" "imgui_impl_android.h")

target_include_directories(CMakeTarget PRIVATE "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/android/"
                                                "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/sources/android/native_app_glue/")

target_link_libraries(CMakeTarget
  PRIVATE
    imgui::imgui
)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMakeTarget PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

It works partially but according to example of android imgui example, it needs

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
```

I changed to:

```
#include "log.h"
#include "android_native_app_glue.h"
#include "asset_manager.h"
```

It started to give several errors for cannot open source file. The errors were for poll.h, pthread.h, sched.h, android/configuration.h, etc. It seems to me that I need to inlcude android ndk completely but

```
include(AndroidNdkGdb)
include(AndroidNdkModules)
```

gives error in cmake even when I installed android ndk and sdk.

I want to be able to use android libraries in my cross-platform project in visual studio 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by updating CMakeLists.txt to:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform), include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform)")

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Users/HP/source/repos/CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform)/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/")

find_package(imgui REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeTarget "CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform).cpp" "CMakeProject3 (imgui Cross-platform).h" "imgui_android.cpp" "imgui_impl_android.cpp" "imgui_impl_android.h")

target_include_directories(CMakeTarget PRIVATE "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/"
                                                "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/sources/android/native_app_glue/"
                                                "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/asm/")

target_link_libraries(CMakeTarget
  PRIVATE
    imgui::imgui
)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMakeTarget PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```